# Getting libevent error when running installing tmux

Tags: tmux

configure: error: "libevent not found" when installing tmux

I downloaded the tmux tarball and trying to install it. I cannot connect to git on the server i am trying to install.  This for a new Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) server.
I am new to Linux and never did installation as a root :)

```
[tmux-master]# ./configure && make
...
configure: error: "libevent not found"
```

Can you please suggest me how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

tmux depends on libevent. If you are using RHEL there is a libevent-devel package you can install.

But I think on RHEL6.5 it is libevent 1.4 which is very old (you normally need 2.x). 1.4 will still work with tmux but you need to make this change in tmux's control.c around line 79:

```
-               line = evbuffer_readln(c->stdin_data, NULL, EVBUFFER_EOL_LF);
+               /* line = evbuffer_readln(c->stdin_data, NULL, EVBUFFER_EOL_LF); */
```

Another option is to build libevent 2.x yourself but that is probably more complicated for you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using an alias as mentioned in the below link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/why-cant-gcc-find-libevent-when-building-tmux-from-source/17918

Answer (score 0):

Really, the real answer to this question is installing event2 with yum. 
Use the following two commands--one erase, and then install:

```
sudo yum erase libevent-devel
sudo yum install libevent2-devel
```

TMUX should work after this.

If you want to keep the older version for consistency sake, you should not use the first (erase) command.